# Jquery.InputMask : Own Mask Creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, mask

I use [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask) for a forms  and I want to create my own mask. So I tried [using this tutorial](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/wiki/Howto:-Create-your-own-mask) to make my own workaround.

```
    Inputmask.extendDefinitions({
    '~': {
        validator: "[,\\.]",
        cardinality: 1
    }
});
```

When I try it, the "." works but not the "," and I can't figure out why.

I also tried this

```
    Inputmask.extendDefinitions({
    '~': {
        validator: function (chrs, buffer, pos, strict, opts) 
            {
                return new RegExp("[,\\.]").test(chrs);
            },
        cardinality: 1
    }
});
```

But had the same problem.

This is the mask I use:

```
jQuery("input").inputmask("[9]{0,6}~9{0,2}",{ "placeholder": "" , "clearMaskOnLostFocus": false });
```

So how could I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was due to a conflict between two plug-in. So this code works fine.